# Angular Favourite Row with checkboxes in star form for adding projects to a different table

Tags: angular, list, row, favorites

I have an Angular4 project and a table with projects.
Projects will have different columns like ID, Name, Costs, ...

now I want to add a Row with checkboxes in Star Form for adding projects in a favourite List. How can I do it in Angular4 (not Angular Material or AngularJS) like this?

Both tables should be shown in the same component "projects"
The  [x] will be a star and its filled yellow if star-icon will be clicked.
Then the project will be putted in the favourite list.

```
Project Table:
|Favourite|ID|Name|Costs|...|
| [X]     |1 |A   |500  |...|
| [ ]     |2 |B   |600  |...|
| [X]     |3 |C   |750  |...|
| [ ]     |4 |D   |200  |...|

Favourite Table:
|ID|Name|Costs|...|
|1 |A   |500  |...|
|3 |C   |750  |...|

==UPDATE==

HTML-table row with checkboxes:
<tr *ngFor="let project of projects">
   <td>
       <input type="checkbox" [value]="project" (click)="favourite($event)"/> 
   </td>
</tr>

HTML-Favourite Table
<tbody>
   <tr *ngFor="let f of favouriteProjects">
       <td>
           <span>
                {{f.id}}
           </span>
       </td>
       <td>
           <span>
                {{f.title}}
           </span>
       </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>

TS:
...
    private projects: Project[] = [];
    private favouriteProjects: Project[] = [];
...
favourite(ev){
        this.favouriteProjects.push(ev.target.defaultValue);
    }
```

Comment: set a property 'stared' true for which user clicks from the 1st table and set the css with the help of this property on the column as well. For second table filter the array based on the property 'starred' true and pass it to the component.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to save the favourites in a array to save them. It's not just a filter.

Comment: So, each time you making an object to stared, make an API call and update the db with stared true, and keep it in sync with UI, so when you refresh the page you get the same array that can show the same result.

Comment: I updated the Question with some code parts to show how I try to do it.

Comment: added the answer and basic code functionality. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make an API call, for each of the item that you are adding in the favorite array or once send the all array. I have create the code boilerplate, you can refer this and implement solution. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-anzpya?file=src/app/table/table.component.ts) is stackblitz link.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;
  projects = [];
  favProjects = [];
  constructor(){
    // get this data from API
    // After getting the data from API make fav property false if it is not in the API response

    // Ideally if you are mainting it on backend level it should be the in the object.
    this.projects = [
      {name: 'Abhinav', age: 15, fav:false, id:1}, // id for unique identifier
      {name: 'Ravi', age: 23, fav:false, id:2},
      {name: 'Kalam', age: 35, fav:false, id:3},
      {name: 'Sunny', age: 25, fav:false, id:4},
    ];
    
    // check if from API is any favriout project is there add it to the favriout table
    this.initFavProject();
  }
  // load the fav project if user saved it earlier in the db
  initFavProject(){
    for(let i = 0 ; i < this.projects.length; i++){
      if(this.projects[i].fav){
        this.favProjects.push(Object.assign({},this.projects[i]));
      }
    }
  }

  addItemToFav(e){
    this.projects = this.projects.filter((item)=> item.id !== e.id);
    e.fav = true;
    // make an API all and send the upadte for row 'e', so next time user 
    // reload the webpage, its fav property will be true and it will automatically go to the favriout table.

    // Either save each time one object or all the favProjects array at once based on the click
    this.favProjects.push(Object.assign({},e));
  }

  saveFavTODB(){
    // access the this.favProjects and send it to the database to save a new one or update the exhisting one.
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h3>Project Table</h3>

<app-table [tableData]="projects" [allowFavrout]="true" (favEvent)="addItemToFav($event)"></app-table>

<h3>Favrout Project</h3>
<app-table [tableData]="favProjects"></app-table>
```

**table.component.html**

```
<table border="1" *ngIf="tableData && tableData.length > 0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th *ngIf="allowFavrout">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of tableData">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.age}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="allowFavrout"><button (click)="addToFav(item)">Add To Favriout</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**table.component.ts**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  templateUrl: './table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./table.component.css']
})
export class TableComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() tableData : Array<any> = [];
  @Input() allowFavrout = false;
  @Output() favEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  addToFav(item){
    this.favEvent.emit(item)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for your help! That works for me =)